# how to plot a pie chart from a dataframe using crosstab function in python

Tags: python, plotly, pie-chart, crosstab

i am trying to plot a pie chart using  crosstab function from 2 columns in a dataframe where until now i am able to plot a bar chart using the below statement.

## sample of the dataframe:

[image]

```
pd.crosstab(df['event_location'],df['event_type']).iplot(kind="bar", bins=20, theme="white", title="Event type over Location",xTitle='location', yTitle='Number of person')
```

[image]

my question is how to convert this bar chart into a pie chart ?

Comment: Please add some test data for us to work on!

Comment: @Grayrigel what you mean by test data ?

Comment: A small part of the data in the tex form that we can copy-paste and plot the desired pie chart. Please don't add image as data can't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to display the number of occurrences for every event type. This simple code will help you plot pie charts per location.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ct = pd.crosstab(df['event_location'],df['event_type'])
ct.plot.pie(subplots=True)
plt.legend(title='XYZ')
plt.show()
```